# Sorting Data Into Clumps With Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, histogram

I'd like to clump a list of data based off a list of ranges. The idea being that I'd like to make a histogram of the end result.  I know about collections.Counter but have not seen someone us it or other built in to generate clumps.   I have written out the long form but am hoping someone can offer up something that is more efficient.

```
def min_to_sec(val):
    ret_val = 60 * int(val)
    return ret_val

def hr_to_sec(val):
    ret_val = 3600 * int(val)
    return ret_val

def histogram(y_lst):
    x_lst = [   10,
                20,
                30,
                40,
                50,
                60,
                90,
                min_to_sec(2),
                min_to_sec(3),
                min_to_sec(4),
                min_to_sec(5),
                min_to_sec(10),
                min_to_sec(15),
                min_to_sec(20),
            ]

    results = {}    
    for y_val in y_lst:
        for x_val in x_lst:
            if y_val < x_val:
                results[ str(x_val) ] = results.get( str(x_val), 0) + 1
                break
        else:        
            results['greater'] = results.get('greater', 0) + 1
    return results
```

*Updated to include an example of desired sample output:*

So if my x_lst and y_list are:

```
x_lst = [10,20,30,40]
y_lst = [1,2,3,15,22,27,40]
```

I'd like a return value similar to Counter, of:

```
{
    10:3,
    20:1,
    30:2,
}
```

So while my above code works, being that it's a nested for loop, it's quite slow, and I'm hoping there's a way to use something like collections.Count to do this 'clumping' operation.

Comment: Rephrased and got the answer I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791571/how-to-group-count-list-elements-by-range

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do this kind of counting of elements in a list:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: Counter([1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 100])
Out[2]: Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 100: 1, 10: 1})
```

You can increment a Counter more simply using:

```
results['foo'] += 1
```

In order to count only those before the inequality, you could use [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
In [3]: from itertools import takewhile 

In [4]: Counter(takewhile(lambda x: x < 10, [1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 100]))
Out[4]: Counter({1: 1, 2: 1})
```

*However this won't keep track of those which have broken out of the takewhile.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using pandas? You could put `y_lst` into a DataFrame and pretty easily make a histogram.

Assuming you have matplotlib and pylab imported...

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 15, 22, 27, 40])
data[0].hist(bins = 4)
```

That would give you the histogram you describe above. However, once the data is in a pandas DataFrame it's not too challenging to slice it up however you'd like.